# Docke-sync issue : i am running the docker-sync start cmd and i got an error

Tags: docker, docker-machine

i'm workin on windows 10 OS, im already running docker on my machine as you can see in the picture
and i am trying to run " docker-sync start" on a sub-system linux ( an app ( named Debian) I installed from Microsoft store ) and i got the error i shared in the picture, the sub-system doesn't detect docker desktop on my machine.

anyone has an idea how te resolve this ?

this is my image error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Docker from command line worked for me.

---

Stop Docker:

```
test -z "$(docker ps -q 2>/dev/null)" && osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'
```

Start Docker:

```
open --background -a Docker
```